# Capture link tracking in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

There is google analytics used on the page. One of its functions is to track clicked links. After the link is clicked the GET-request is sent.
My code has to register such a request after specific link is clicked.
How does it look now? The required page is loaded, then `onResourceRequested` handler is set. Now it just logs every `requestData.url` to console. Then the link click is emulated and `wait(2000)` is used to wait for this request.
However, this exact analytics request is not logged.
My minimal code looks like this:

```
const casper = require("casper").create();

const ADDRESS = "https://example.com/";
const SELECTOR = "#button";

function resourceRequestedHandler(casper, requestData, request) {
    console.log(requestData.url);
}

casper.start(ADDRESS, function() {
    casper.options.onResourceRequested = resourceRequestedHandler;
    this.click(SELECTOR);
    this.wait(5000);
});

casper.run();
```

I see two other analytics requests, but not the one I actually need.

Then I've added debugging:

```
const casper = require("casper").create();

casper.on('page.error', function(msg, trace) {
  this.echo('Error: ' + msg, 'ERROR');
  for(var i=0; i<trace.length; i++) {
      var step = trace[i];
      this.echo('   ' + step.file + ' (line ' + step.line + ')', 'ERROR');
  }
});

...
```

and now I see this error message:

```
Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
   https://example.com/ (line 1)
    (line 0)
   https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-N77ZNG (line 5727)
   https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-N77ZNG (line 5729)
   https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-N77ZNG (line 5629)
   https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-N77ZNG (line 5646)
   https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-N77ZNG (line 5609)
   https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-N77ZNG (line 5647)
   https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-N77ZNG (line 5647)
   https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-N77ZNG (line 5647)
   https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-N77ZNG (line 5649)
   https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-N77ZNG (line 5655)
   https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-N77ZNG (line 5654)
   https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-N77ZNG (line 5657)
   https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-N77ZNG (line 5658)
Error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'isi.offset().top')
   https://example.com/sites/g/files/qhldwo1226/files/js/js_pRAAd8Zu6jlSeEw2taM6IolaW3NYjhhsBhikiOHSiuE.js (line 4064)
```

I've tried to add jQuery implicicitly with

```
const casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts: ['jquery-3.2.1.js']   
});
```

but had no success.

I'm confused and have no ideas how to register the necessary request. It's not a test script, it's just a standalone script.

Thank you.

Comment: hi there, it seems like the issue is on the page itself, try getting more information about the steps using `require('casper').create({verbose : true, logLevel : "debug"})`,
Also 5s might not be enough to catch the desired request, i would recommend using a recursive with `casper.wait(time, recursive_function)`, don't forget to limit the executions so it won't run forever.

Comment: Thank you! I've also decided that the issue is on the page, as it appeared to work fine on different site but in the similar situation.
I'll debug it in detail after I switch to this task back.